# How Google Analytics bypass Same Origin policy when the analytics call is from an IFRAME?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, same-origin-policy, browser-security

**HOW IT GETS THE PARENT URL WHEN THE GA CALL IS FROM WITHIN AN IFRAME?**

Normally when javascript tries to access anything outside its frame browser throws the SAME ORIGIN POLICY Error. Especially for parent.document, parent.location etc. However, when you inspect the analytics data send going back to the server it is clear that the call carries the URL of window.top.  It is nearly impossible to do this and I believe they are doing either a clever hack or are getting preferential treatment.

Example:
Page : http://delhincr.kidzania.com/en-in/pages/virtual-tour
IFRAME SRC : http://walkinto.in/tour/W1vLiH5CbG-yePUsrc0WM (clearly not sameorigin)

GA Call from IFRAME :

https://www.google-analytics.com/r/collect?v=1&_v=j71&a=944377214&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=**http%3A%2F%2Fwalkinto.in%2Ftour%2FW1vLiH5CbG-yePUsrc0WM**&dr=**http%3A%2F%2Fdelhincr.kidzania.com%2Fen-in%2Fpages%2Fvirtual-tour**&ul=en-us&de=UTF-8&dt=KidZania%20Delhi%20NCR&sd=24-bit&sr=1366x768&vp=1140x641&je=0&_u=CBCAAEAB~&jid=1584760177&gjid=1030794988&cid=770600375.1539312411&tid=UA-50632293-1&_gid=1805256933.1539654946&_r=1&z=1389492630

How does Google bypass this? Could it be using postMessage from the GA within IFRAME to the GA on parent page?

Comment: `are getting preferential treatment` you think the browsers have a back door for google? browsers like MicroSoft Edge and Mozilla Firefox?

Comment: :)  No I did not think there was a conspiracy really.  Just wanted to understand how it was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (parent) URL is accessible inside an iframe with "document.referrer" if there is no constraint from the main page (like CSP).

Comment: Thank you!  I tested it with a fiddle.  Seems to be working fine.  Will update back if I find any complications elsewhere.  https://jsfiddle.net/boni/rnegk3cL/